# Can a system be inconsistent and have free variables?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm learning about linear independence/dependence in linear algebra. It is easy to tell if a system is linearly dependent if it has free variables. However, I've come upon a problem where the matrix I'm working with is inconsistent. If I have a system that is inconsistent, can there still be free variables?

Comment: Once you find that your system is inconsistent there really isn't anything else you can do with it, so I don't see much point in trying to classify variables as *free* or not.

Comment: @gotit--thanks There are many applications of linear algebra where the resulting system is inconsistent, and where we still really find much to do with it. This is primarily the case in the study of overdetermined systems -- in statistics, and more recently, machine learning.

Answer (score 3):

Sure:
$$
\begin{cases}
x+y=0\\
x+y=1
\end{cases}
$$
The rank of the incomplete matrix is $1$, so one variable is free, but the system is inconsistent.

But this might depend on the definition of *free variable* to begin with.